# Unable to load sketch: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x41

Tags: uploading, bootloader, sketch

I've stumbled upon what I've later found it's quite common error, but there seems not to be simple troubleshooting way and solution (people often try various things, sometimes they succeed, sometimes not).

I am using [DAGU mini driver](http://www.dawnrobotics.co.uk/dagu-arduino-mini-driver-board/), I was able to load sketch as described [here](http://blog.dawnrobotics.co.uk/2013/11/getting-started-with-the-dagu-arduino-mini-driver-board/) - chose Arduino NG ATMega8 as board, connect to my PC via USB (with the driver listed on the [product page](http://www.dawnrobotics.co.uk/dagu-arduino-mini-driver-board/)).

Later on I've plugged RedBot wheel encoders sensor and write some simplistic program to check whether it works at all. I've summarized the steps in a github [issue](https://github.com/BartAdv/rowboat/issues/1), so that it's easy to reference it.

When I tried to upload the sketch I've receiced `stk500_initialize(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x42`, `stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x41`. The full log is included in comment on that github issue.

The D13 diode is making series of 3-blink bursts - 8 bursts after start. More diagnostic I did in the github issue as well.

My question (apart from obvious 'how to fix it!?!' ;) ) is whether there is some kind of documentation for this protocol? On the various topics I've found people seem to have somewhat different problems (the numbers and messages were different). I just want to know why the first few messages are exchanged OK (avrdude receives some basic info from the chip), but later ones (namely `Send: A [41] . [81]   [20]`) are producing protocol errors.

Comment: Ordered programmer, will see if it's just corrupted bootloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVR programmer helped.

Meaning the bootloader somewhat got corrupted and I had to burn new one.